# Animate multiple UIViews at the same time

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

I have a bunch (9 or so) `UIButton`'s that I'd like to animate simultaneously. I basically want them all to fade in, but at different points in time. So viewOne.alpha will fade in at time t+.1, viewTwo will fade in at time t+.15, viewThree will fade in at time t+.17, etc.

They should all fade in at random speeds as well.

I'm thinking I can accomplish this with `CABasicAnimation`? My question is basically if I can animate multiple things at once, since I can't seem to use multiple `UIViewAnimation` blocks at once.

Comment: You can do this with the animateKeyframes block method.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this with one UIView animation block, but you can setup animation blocks in the future with ['performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:). For example:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(fadeIn:) withObject:button1 afterDelay:0.1f];
[self performSelector:@selector(fadeIn:) withObject:button2 afterDelay:0.15f];

- (void)fadeIn:(UIView *)view {
    // start animation with random speed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use 
[+ animateKeyframesWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:](https://goo.gl/BxTGiI) method. E.g.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

static NSTimeInterval const kButtonsAnimationDuration = 1.0;
static NSTimeInterval const kButtonsAnimationDelay = 0.0;

#define ARC4RANDOM_MAX 0x100000000

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *buttons;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self animateButtons];
}

- (void)animateButtons {
    double startTimes[] = {0.1, 0.15, 0.17, 0.22, 0.24}; // must be equal to the number of buttons in the array self.buttons
    double *startTimesPtr = startTimes;
    [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:kButtonsAnimationDuration delay:kButtonsAnimationDelay options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationModeLinear animations:^{
        for (NSUInteger i = 0u; i < self.buttons.count; ++i) {
            double startTime = startTimesPtr[i];
            UIButton *button = self.buttons[i];
            [self addKeyframeWithButton:button startTime:startTime];
        }
    } completion:nil];
}

- (void)addKeyframeWithButton:(UIButton *)button startTime:(double)startTime {
    double correctedStartTime = startTime / kButtonsAnimationDuration;
    double randomDuration = ((double)arc4random() / ARC4RANDOM_MAX);

    button.alpha = 0.0;
    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:correctedStartTime relativeDuration:randomDuration animations:^{
        button.alpha = 1.0;
    }];
}

@end
```